# how we can run two threads parallely in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to run two threads parallely. My requirement is :- In database there are two tables - table1 and table2. In table1 there are 1000 records. One thread will read 100 rows from table1 and pass these rows data to thread two. thread two will insert these rows into table2. When thread One get data from table1 then thread two should be in waiting state and when thread two inserting data into table Two then thread One shuld be in waiting state. How we can do this.

Hi, I have written this code. Please share me your views how we can improve this code also use wait and notify methods for threads..

class ProcessDataUsingThread extends Thread {

```
private Connection con = null;
private Statement st = null;
//  private String query = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private int i = 0;
private int totalRows = 0;
static ProcessDataUsingThread t1;
static ProcessToInsertData t2;
// ArrayList al;

public static void main(String... arg) {
    t1 = new ProcessDataUsingThread();
    t1.setName("Thread-1");
    t1.start();
    // t2.start();
    //   t2.suspend();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    fetchRecord();
}

public void fetchRecord() {

    try {
        con = new DatabaseConnection().getConnection();
        st = con.createStatement();
        // Find Total no. of rows in tha table
        ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery("select count(*) As Rows from customer;");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            totalRows = resultSet.getInt("Rows");
        }
        System.out.println("Total no. of rows are : " + totalRows);

        while (i <= totalRows) {
            System.out.println(getName() + " is getting execute. . . .");
            rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from Customer LIMIT " + i + ", 10");
            i += 10;

            //  t1.suspend();
            new ProcessToInsertData(rs, t1).start();
            t1.suspend();
            // t2.notify(); 
            //  t2.start(); 
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //  return al; 
}
```

}

/**
 * Second class for thread
 *
 * @author abc
 */
class ProcessToInsertData extends Thread {

```
private Connection con = null;
private final int BATCH_EXECUTION_LIMIT = 20;
private int counter = 0;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private ProcessDataUsingThread pd = null;

public ProcessToInsertData(ResultSet resultSet, ProcessDataUsingThread pd) {
    this.rs = resultSet;
    this.pd = pd;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        con = new DatabaseConnection().getConnection();
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customer_temp (C_ID, C_Name, C_Mob_No, C_City)                           VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        System.out.println("Executing " + getName());
        while (rs.next()) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
            preparedStatement.setString(2, rs.getString("C_Name"));
            preparedStatement.setLong(3, rs.getLong("C_Mob_No"));
            preparedStatement.setString(4, rs.getString("C_City"));
            preparedStatement.addBatch();
            counter++;

            System.out.println("INSERT INTO Customer_Temp (C_ID, C_Name, C_Mob_No, C_City) VALUES('" + rs.getInt(1) + "','" + rs.getString(2) + "','" + rs.getInt(3) + "','" + rs.getString("C_City") + "')");

            if (counter % BATCH_EXECUTION_LIMIT == 0) {
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();
                System.out.println("After batch execution. . . .Counter :" + counter);
            }
        }
        if (counter % BATCH_EXECUTION_LIMIT != 0) {
            preparedStatement.executeBatch();
            System.out.println("Outer If...after batch execution. . . .Counter :" + counter);
        }
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        pd.resume();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Please help me....
Thanks in advance

Comment: uhm, i should use prepared statements, it would be more efficient... Just get a row, and then insert that in other table in a loop.

Comment: Do you know how to start/run one thread (other than the main java thread)? In the same way you run two. Read a tutorial on threads. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need threads at all (everything can run sequentially according to your own description). So this is not a direct answer to your question, but just a general description of how you can apply multi-threading in your program.

**For each activity, declare a class that implements Runnable. For example:**

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable
{
    private String input  = null;
    private String output = null;

    public MyClass(String input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String getOutput()
    {
        return output;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        output = func(input);
    }
}
```

**In the main activity, start all the threads, and wait for each thread to complete only where you actually need its output. For example:**

```
public String myFunc(String input) throws Exception
{
    MyClass object = new MyClass(input);
    Thread  thread = new Thread(object);

    thread.start();
    // Do whatever you wanna do...
    // ...
    // ...
    // And when you need the thread's output:
    thread.join();
    return object.getOutput();
}
```